# Why does it save only one element instead of the whole list?

Tags: c

I'm making a program where the user is supposed add a pack of pasta as the last element of a list, delete the first element of the list or visualize the whole list.

However, when I try to add new elements and visualize the list, it only shows the last element that I've introduced and only saves that element. The program is supposed to save the list in a txt file.

If there are some parts that are unclear, I apologize as English is not my first language and I do not program in English.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* struct to represent a pack of pasta */
struct Pasta {
  char type[20];
  char brand[20];
  int time;
  int raffInt;
};

typedef struct Pasta PASTA;

/* struct to represent a list */
struct Nodo {
  PASTA p;
  struct Nodo *next;
};

typedef struct Nodo *NODO;

/******************************************************************************
 ********************* ADD THE LAST ELEMENT OF THE LIST ***********************
 ******************************************************************************/

/* function that read a pack of pasta */
PASTA leggiPasta() {
  PASTA pasta;    

  /* insert the type */
  printf("What type of pasta?\n");
  scanf("%s", &pasta.type);

  /* insert the brand */
  printf("Which brand?\n");
  scanf("%s", &pasta.brand);

  /* insert the time to be cooked */
  printf("Time to be cooked?\n");
  scanf("%d", &pasta.time);

  /* determine if it is whole or refined*/
  do {
    printf("Is it whole (PRESS 1) or refined (PRESS 2)?\n");
    scanf("%d", &pasta.raffInt);
    /* if the value is not valid */
    if(pasta.raffInt != 1 && pasta.raffInt != 2)
      printf("Not valid\n");
  } while(pasta.raffInt != 1 && pasta.raffInt != 2);
  return pasta;
}

/* function to insert a pack of pasta at the bottom of the list */
NODO insert(NODO list) {
  
  NODO new;
  nuovo = malloc(sizeof(struct Nodo));

  /* fill the parts of the pack */
  nuovo -> p = leggiPasta();
  printf("\n");
  new -> next = NULL;

  while (list -> next != NULL)
    list = list -> next;

    /* now list contains the address of the last element of the list */
    list -> next = new;

  return new;
}

/******************************************************************************
 *********************************** PRINT ************************************
 ******************************************************************************/

/* function to print a pack of pasta */
void printPasta(PASTA p) {
  /* print the type */
  printf("Type: %s\n", p.typo);
  /* print the brand */
  printf("Brand: %s\n", p.brand);
  /* print the time */
  printf("Time to be cooked: %d min\n", p.time);
  /* whole or refined */
  if(p.raffInt == 1)
    printf("Whole\n");
  else
    printf("Refined\n");
}

/* function to print a list */
void print(NODO list) {
  NODO nodo = list;
  /* if the list is empty, you don't have to do anything */
  if(nodo != NULL) {
    printf("\nHere's the list:\n");
    while (nodo != NULL) {
      printPasta(nodo -> p);
      nodo = nodo -> next;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
  }
  else
    printf("Nothing to print\n\n");
}

/******************************************************************************
 ************************** DELETE THE FIRST ELEMENT **************************
 ******************************************************************************/

/* function to delete the first element of the list */
NODO delete(NODO list) {
  NODO current;    

  /* if the list is empty, you don't have to do anything */
  if(list == NULL)
    current = NULL;
  else {
    current = list -> next; 
    free(list);
    printf("Deleted\n\n");
  }
  return current;
}

/******************************************************************************
 ************************************ FILE ************************************
 ******************************************************************************/

/* function for the acquisition of a list from a file */
NODO acquisition() {
  FILE *fp = fopen("pasta.txt", "r");   //to read a txt file
  NODO head = NULL;       //head of the list
  NODO current;           
  NODO previous;          

  PASTA pasta;            //a pack of pasta
  int read;              //if it was read or not

  /* if the file is empty, do nothing */
  if(fp != NULL) {
   ead r = fread(&pasta, sizeof(PASTA), 1, fp);
    if (read) {    //it was read
      /* read the first one */
      head = malloc(sizeof(struct Nodo));
      head -> p = pasta;

      /* keep track of the last one */
      previous = head;
      /* read the rest of them */
      do {
        /* read a new one */
        read = fread(&pasta, sizeof(PASTA), 1, fp);
        if (read) {    //it was read
          
          current = malloc(sizeof(struct Nodo));
          current -> p = pasta;

          /* connect it to the previous one */
          previous -> next = current;

          /* the new one becomes the precedent */
          previous = current;
        }
        else  
          previous -> next = NULL;
      } while(letto);
        printf("List retrieved\n\n");
    }
    else
      printf("List empty\n\n");
      fclose(fp);

  }
  else
    printf("Couldn't open it\n\n");
  return head;
}

/* function to save a list in a file */
void save(NODO list) {
  FILE *fp = fopen("pasta.txt", "w");   //to write a txt file

  /* if it's empty do nothing */
  if(fp != NULL) {
    while (list != NULL) {   //go ahead while it has elements
      fwrite(&(list -> p), sizeof(struct Nodo), 1, fp);
      lista = list -> next;    //proceed
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("Saved successfully\n\n");
  }
  else
    printf("Couldn't save\n\n");
}

/* main function */
int main() {
  NODO list = acquisition();      //create the list
  int answer = -1;                //to interact with the user

  while (answer != 0) {
    /* choose the operation */
    printf("What do you want to do?\n");
    printf("1 -> Insert a new pack of past\n");
    printf("2 -> Delete the first element of the list\n");
    printf("3 -> Visualise the list\n");
    printf("0 -> Finish the program\n");
    scanf("%d", &answer);

    /* insert */
    if(answer == 1) {
      list = insert(list);
    }

    /* delete */
    else if(answer == 2) {
      list = delete(list);
    }

    /* visualise */
    else if(answer == 3) {
      print(list);
    }

    /* finish the program */
    else if (answer == 0) {
      printf("Finished, goodbye\n\n");
    }

    /* wrong number */
    else if (answer != 0) {
      printf("It has no meaning, \n\n");
    }

  }
  save(list);
}
```

Comment: did you step through the code, line by line in a debugger?  That is the first thing to do

Comment: This example feels like it could be made smaller.  It also doesn't compile on my system.

Comment: If you dump the whole code, make it compile at least. Hint to your problem, look at `list = insert(list);`

Comment: I did compile it, there were no syntax error, everything works except that it only saves the last element introduced. I agree, that  it could be made smaller, but I followed the instructions my teacher gave me. @StephenNewell,

Comment: Some errors I get (warnings excluded), e.g. 1. "error: 'nuovo' undeclared", 2. "error: 'PASTA' {aka 'struct Pasta'} has no member named 'typo'", 3. "error: unknown type name 'ead'", ... so at least some things got mangled. The easiest way would be to copy and paste, then you can be sure nothing is lost on the way.

Comment: @OlafDietsche That's likely because I had to translate the code from italian to english, so something was lost in the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- there were some translation errors: it is recommended to use English for all identifiers in your code to make it easier to collaborate with other programmers. I am not a native speaker either, but this habit proved very effective for me for the last 40 years.
- hiding pointers behind typedefs is confusing and error prone. Use `typedef struct Node Node;` and use `Node *`.
- the file **pasta.txt** is actually a binary file as you write the contents of the `struct Pasta` as stored in memory directly to it. You should use a different name and open it as binary with `"rb"` and `"wb"`.
- using a textual format instead of binary is **much preferred** for portability, readability, extensibility.
- function `acquisition()` should not make a special case of the first element read.
- the function `insert()` crashes is the `list` is empty. You should test for this and return `nuovo` if `list` is a null pointer.
- the function `insert()` should return the `list`, not the last element added unless the list was initially empty. **this is causing the problem stated**.
- do not use `&` in front of arrays passed to `scanf()` and do pass the maximum number of bytes to read:

  ```
    scanf("%19s", pasta.typo);
  ```
- when writing to the file, you should use the size of `struct Pasta` instead of `struct Nodo`. To avoid this silly mistake, use `sizeof(list->p)`.

Here is a modified version you can study:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* struct to represent a pack of pasta */
typedef struct Pasta Pasta;
struct Pasta {
    char type[20];
    char brand[20];
    int time;
    int raffInt;
};

/* struct to represent a list */
typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node {
    Pasta p;
    Node *next;
};

/* function that read a pack of pasta */
Pasta leggiPasta(void) {
    Pasta pasta;

    /* insert the type */
    printf("What type of pasta?\n");
    scanf("%19s", pasta.type);

    /* insert the brand */
    printf("Which brand?\n");
    scanf("%19s", pasta.brand);

    /* insert the time to be cooked */
    printf("Time to be cooked?\n");
    scanf("%d", &pasta.time);

    /* determine if it is whole or refined*/
    for (;;) {
        printf("Is it whole (PRESS 1) or refined (PRESS 2)?\n");
        scanf("%d", &pasta.raffInt);
        /* if the value is not valid */
        if (pasta.raffInt == 1 || pasta.raffInt == 2)
            break;
        printf("Not valid\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return pasta;
}

/* function to insert a pack of pasta at the bottom of the list */
Node *insert(Node *list) {
    Node *new_node = calloc(sizeof(*new_node), 1);

    /* fill the parts of the pack */
    new_node->p = leggiPasta();
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if (list == NULL) {
        list = new_node;
    } else {
        Node *tail = list;
        while (tail->next != NULL)
            tail = tail->next;

        /* now tail contains the address of the last element of the list */
        tail->next = new_node;
    }
    return list;
}

/* function to print a pack of pasta */
void printPasta(Pasta p) {
    /* print the type */
    printf("Type: %s\n", p.type);
    /* print the brand */
    printf("Brand: %s\n", p.brand);
    /* print the time */
    printf("Time to be cooked: %d min\n", p.time);
    /* whole or refined */
    if (p.raffInt == 1)
        printf("Whole\n");
    else
        printf("Refined\n");
}

/* function to print a list */
void print(Node *list) {
    Node *node = list;
    /* if the list is empty, you don't have to do anything */
    if (node != NULL) {
        printf("\nHere's the list:\n");
        while (node != NULL) {
            printPasta(node->p);
            node = node->next;
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    } else {
        printf("Nothing to print\n\n");
    }
}

/* function to delete the first element of the list */
Node *delete(Node *list) {
    Node *current;

    /* if the list is empty, you don't have to do anything */
    if (list == NULL) {
        current = NULL;
    } else {
        current = list->next;
        free(list);
        printf("Deleted\n\n");
    }
    return current;
}

/* function for the acquisition of a list from a file */
Node *acquisition(void) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("pasta.txt", "r");   //to read a txt file
    Node *head = NULL;       //head of the list
    Node *tail = NULL;
    Node *current;
    Pasta pasta;            //a pack of pasta
    int count = 0;

    /* if the file is empty, do nothing */
    if (fp != NULL) {
        char buf[100];
        while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
            if (sscanf(buf, "%19[^,],%19[^,],%d,%d",
                       pasta.type, pasta.brand,
                       &pasta.time, &pasta.raffInt) == 4)
            {
                count++;
                /* allocate a new node */
                current = calloc(sizeof(*current), 1);
                current->p = pasta;
                current->next = NULL;
                if (tail == NULL) {
                    tail = head = current;
                } else {
                    tail = tail->next = current;
                }
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "invalid format: %s", buf);
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
        if (count) {
            printf("List retrieved: %d elements\n\n", count);
        } else {
            printf("List empty\n\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("Couldn't open file\n\n");
    }
    return head;
}

/* function to save a list in a file */
int save(Node *list) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("pasta.txt", "w");   //to write a txt file
    if (fp != NULL) {
        while (list != NULL) {   //go ahead while it has elements
            fprintf(fp, "%s,%s,%d,%d\n",
                    list->p.type, list->p.brand,
                    list->p.time, list->p.raffInt);
            list = list->next;    //proceed
        }
        fclose(fp);
        printf("Saved successfully\n\n");
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("Couldn't save\n\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

/* main function */
int main() {
    Node *list = acquisition();      //create the list
    int answer;                      //to interact with the user

    for (;;) {
        /* choose the operation */
        printf("What do you want to do?\n");
        printf("1 -> Insert a new pack of past\n");
        printf("2 -> Delete the first element of the list\n");
        printf("3 -> Visualise the list\n");
        printf("0 -> Finish the program\n");
        if (scanf("%d", &answer) != 1)
            break;

        if (answer == 1) {
            /* insert */
            list = insert(list);
        } else
        if (answer == 2) {
            /* delete */
            list = delete(list);
        } else
        if (answer == 3) {
            /* visualise */
            print(list);
        } else
        if (answer == 0) {
            /* finish the program */
            printf("Finished, goodbye\n\n");
            break;
        } else {
            /* wrong number */
            printf("It has no meaning\n\n");
        }
    }
    return save(list);
}
```